# Woocommerce multiply the quantity of a specific product in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is there any way to multiply the quantity of specific product in cart?

Lets say I have multiple products in the cart and one of the products has quantity "3", I want to multiply the quantity with "5" so [3*5] and update the quantity field to "15".

I want to do it for **only one specific product** in cart and not for all.

Answer (score 1):

It depends where and when you want to change it.

I can think of two different approaches:

PHP:

```
$woocommerce->cart->set_quantity( product_id , product_quantity );
```

JS + AJAX:

You can find a working solution here, just try to adapt it to your needs:

[WooCommerce - change QTY triggers AJAX call in cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32196103/woocommerce-change-qty-triggers-ajax-call-in-cart)

EDIT:

I've coded a simple jQuery example. You can do this on real time while user inputs the quantity in the cart amount input. The user inputs any quantity and when he/she clicks outside or leaves the input focus the amount is automatically changed (x5).

In order to use this you have to edit the cart template in Wordpress. I would strongly recommend using a child theme and following the [Woocommerce template best practices](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/).

```js
$("#input-value").focusout(function() {
    var value = parseFloat($(this).val());
    $(this).val(value*5);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Quantity: <input type="text" id="input-value" />
```

In order to aim for only a specific product you an use some PHP in your cart template to add a 'multiply' class to the quantity container:

```
<?php if($_product->id == your_id) {
?>
    <td class="product-quantity multiply" data-title="<?php _e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
<?php
}else{
?>
    <td class="product-quantity" data-title="<?php _e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
<?php
}
?>

    <?php
        if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) {
            $product_quantity = sprintf( '1 <input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $cart_item_key );
        } else {
            $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
                'input_name'  => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                'input_value' => $cart_item['quantity'],
                'max_value'   => $_product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $_product->get_stock_quantity(),
                'min_value'   => '0'
            ), $_product, false );
        }

        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item );
    ?>
</td>
```

Comment: I want to change the Quantity on CART page for ONLY ONE SPECIFIC product?

Comment: @jose: I tested `$woocommerce->cart->set_quantity( product_id , product_quantity * 5 );` but every time it is multiplying the quantity from the previous value and not with the cart entered value, so I didn't posted my answer.

Comment: @RaunakGupta see my edit in my previous answer. I used javascript to change in real time the input in the cart table. Maybe this is a more suitable approach. What do you think?

Comment: @JoseGomez: I got your point i.e. by managing the full thing at client side, your solution should work. in `cart.php` only this line will do the trick `<td class="product-quantity <?= $product_id == $your_id? 'multiply': ''; ?>" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">` and no need of other PHP code.